# CASE expression yields error when mixing types

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, case

Consider the following:

```
SELECT [DOB] = CASE WHEN [DOB] = '-' then 'invalid date' ELSE cast([DOB] as datetime) 
END
FROM myTable where myID = 73351
```

When `DOB = '-'`, I get the error message:

> Conversion failed when converting datetime from character string.

Which seems to indicate SQL Server tries to cast DOB as `datetime` despite the fact it should only print `'invalid date'`.

Yet consider this which correctly returns `'invalid date'` when `DOB = '-'`.

```
SELECT [DOB] = CASE WHEN [DOB] = '-' then 'invalid date' ELSE 'valid date'
END
FROM myTable where myID = 73351
```

How can I get the first statement to return `'invalid date'` when `DOB = '-'`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The case expression will result in only one data type. You can not have different data types of different rows. The data type in your query will be a `datetime` and `invalid date` is an invalid datetime value.

> How can I get the first statement to return 'invalid date' when DOB =
>   '-' ?

The only way is to not cast the value to `datetime`.

```
CASE WHEN [DOB] = '-' then 'invalid date' ELSE [DOB] END
```

Comment: casting to sql_variant works http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173829(v=sql.90).aspx

Comment: @LastCoder I have never used them. How would they come out on the client side? As binary?

Comment: They would come out on the client side as whatever the underlying type is. Programmatically they would likely be an Object that you would need to explicitly cast. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13823130/are-there-any-benefits-to-using-sql-variant-over-varchar-in-sql-server

Answer (score 1):

You're creating a column that has 2 separate data types, varchar and datetime. Try casting both possibilities as SQL_VARIANT.

```
SELECT [DOB] =
CASE
    WHEN [DOB] = '-' THEN CAST('Invalid' as sql_variant)
    ELSE CAST(CAST([DOB] as DATETIME) as sql_variant)
END
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173829(v=sql.90).aspx